# DataGridViewComboboxCell отобразить список

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Делал всё по инструкции. В Combobox ячейках пусто и ничего не выпадает.
Чего мне не хватает?

```
private DataGridViewComboBoxColumn CreateComboBoxColumn()
{
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn column =
            new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        {
            column.HeaderText = "Products";
            column.DropDownWidth = 90;
            column.Width = 90;
        }
        return column;
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboboxColumn = CreateComboBoxColumn();
    dataGridView3.Columns.Add(comboboxColumn);
    dataGridView3.Rows.Add(3);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {      
                List<string> ordrerProducts = new List<string>();

                ordrerProducts.Add("A"+i);
                ordrerProducts.Add("B"+i);
                ordrerProducts.Add("C"+i);

                var cell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
                cell.Items.AddRange(ordrerProducts);
                //второй вариант (тоже не работает)
                //cell.DataSource = ordrerProducts;

                dataGridView3[0, i] = cell;
     }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вместо `cell.Items.AddRange(ordrerProducts);` нужно `cell.DataSource = ordrerProducts;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Преобразуйте список в массив:

```
cell.Items.AddRange(ordrerProducts.ToArray());
```

У [`DataGridViewComboBoxCell.ObjectCollection.AddRange`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcell.objectcollection.addrange?view=netframework-4.8) есть две перегрузки, но ни одна из них не принимает ни `List` ни `IEnumerable`. В результате если передать список, то он будет воспринят как одно значение.

Исполняемый пример:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        var grid = new DataGridView {Dock = DockStyle.Fill};
        grid.Columns.Add("Column", "Column");
        grid.Rows.Add(3);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            var products = new List<object> { "A" + i, "B" + i, "C" + i };
            var cell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
            cell.Items.AddRange(products.ToArray());
            grid[0,i] = cell;
        }
        var form = new Form();
        form.Controls.Add(grid);
        Application.Run(form);
    }
}
```

Результат:

[image: Демо]

Comment: Спасибо. С двойным индексатором Ваш пример все равно сработал, а AddRange - действительно не сработал со списком. Дальше уже потестил и нашел, что заработало после переустановки нового грида (перед этим был скопирован на форме, что-то где-то с настройками, наверное не то было).                                                                                               
         P.S. Первый мой вопрос на StackOverflow. Вдохновили, мужики! Спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста! Не забудьте [отметить ответ как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Слева от ответа должна быть серая галка. Нажмите на нее. Насчет индексатора я, видимо, поторопился. Поправлю ответ.